# Terminal Mac Os : How to know the executed command?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I am trying to install PyQT and the installation read say I should do the following :

> > python configure.py
> >         Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
> >         Error: PyQt5 requires Qt v5.0 or later. You seem to be using v4.8.6. Use the
> >         --qmake flag to specify the correct version of quake.

```
>> qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.6/lib
```

So I see that qmake is not the right version. But I ask another question : how could I know WHERE is is the executer "qmake" ??? more globally : how to know which executable is run when we type a terminal cmd ?

Thanks
romain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `type`. In the simple case, this looks a lot like `which`:

```
$ type make
make is /usr/bin/make
$ which make
/usr/bin/make
```

However, consider instead:

```
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
$ which [
/bin/[
```

In this case, `type` is correctly telling you that `[ -f . ]` uses an implementation of `[` built into your shell, whereas `which` is incorrectly telling you that the executable in `/bin/[` is used.

The same is true of aliases, shell functions, and the like: `which` only tells you about executables, but `type` tells you what you're running whether or not it's an executable.

Answer (score 1):

PyOt isnt installing because your Qt is outdated.
Try

```
brew install qt
```

if you have homebrew package manager installed. It doesnt download all over again but just updates it.

If you have MacPorts, try

```
sudo port install qt5-mac
```

.It'll update your Qt and QMake versions.

And for knowing the folder where shell commands lie...use

```
which commandname
```

or

```
whereis commandname
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use *which* Command

You need the *which* command. The which(1) man page says, in part:

```
DESCRIPTION
       which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be exe‐
       cuted in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  com‐
       mands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching
       the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.  It
       does not follow symbolic links.
```

### Example

For example, on my system, the command returns the following:

```
$ which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
```

You might also use `which -a qmake` to find *all* the versions found in your *PATH* rather than just the first match. Hope this helps!